# Handling json with $.ajax() in Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Ok, here's the problem.
I've an api that will give me back a json. With success I'll have back a nice list with some values, with an error I'll receive a json containing sone information about the error.
I still haven't tried the "success" case because I still have to deploy the api but I think should work. The problem for now is the "error" case.
Using $.ajax in case of error I'm going to receive three parameters, a xhrequest (or similar), a message and I don't remember.. How can I handle this? In the response body shoulde be a json, where can I find it?

Thanks for any help, sorry for no code or the poor indentantion but I'm writing from my mobile!

Comment: If your API is returning allegedly useful content in the body of an "error" (4xx) response then it's designed wrong

Comment: The error code set up is 500.

Comment: I rest my case - 5xx error codes are supposed to relate to _server_ errors (e.g. lack of resources, etc) and _not_ for application layer errors.

Comment: Yes, I'm not saying that you're wrong, of course an internal server error should represent an "internal server error" but it was like a "requirement" let's say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual body of the response should be available in `jqxhr.responseText`

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it asap and let you know.

Comment: Hm.. there's something that I don't get.. if I use responseText I cannot see anything. Also debugging I can see that the responseText is "" (empty). But if I simply go to the url that I'm using I can clearly see the response. Any help?

Comment: I've just discovered that was a problem of Chrome while running a local server... crazy... thanks btw.

Answer (score 1):

The error callback gets called when it can't get the response from the server (like a 404 error or the like).  If you want to pass back your own errors, you need to put them in the JSON response and test for them in your success callback.

For instance, in a success callback I'm working on right now:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        'url':      'Client/saveClient.mas',
        'dataType': 'json',
        'data':     {
            'first_name'            :   first_name,
            'middle_initials'       :   middle_initials,
            'last_name'             :   last_name,
            'phone_number'          :   phone_number
            },
        'success':  saveClientSuccessCallback,
        'error':  saveClientFailureCallback
    });
  }
}

function saveClientSuccessCallback(json)
{
  if (json.status == 'error')
  {
    updateClientTips(json.error_msg);
  }
  else
  {
    addReadOnlyClient(json.people.values, json.manager_uperson_id);

    jQuery('#new-client-form').dialog("close");
  }
}
function saveClientFailureCallback(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
{
  updateClientTips(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
}
```

As you can see, I return an error condition in json.status and the message in json.error_msg.

Comment: This looks similar on what we're doing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Paul Tomblin said, you have (at least) two options:

- Setting an error code for your response results in `error` being called. In this case, the datatype of the response content is usually nothing to work with, so it is not parsed and put into a `data` variable. But you may access the response text via `jqXHR.responseText` and parse the `JSON` yourself ([.parseJSON()](http://jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.parseJSON)).
- Returning a `200`response with proper `JSON` content, which is parsed automatically into a `data` object (if `dataType` is set to `json`). You can then check `if(data.error) {...}`, get the error message and present it to the user.

I would go for the second option, but it depends on which errors you are expecting.